# Making an consult with javascript and nodejs with mysql librarie

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have the next consult in my code

```
class FirstloginController {


    async getToken(req, res, next) {
        const { token } = req.params;
        const {access_token} = req.query;

        try {
            const decoded = jwt.verify(access_token, process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION)
            res.json({ message: "El acces token es valido", email: decoded})
            const email_consulted = res.json({ email: decoded})
            let select = await pool.query(`SELECT User_email FROM user WHERE User_email=${email_consulted}`)
            if (select != "") {
            const result = await pool.query(`INSERT INTO user (User_email) VALUES (${email_consulted})`);

            }
    
       } catch (err) {
           next(err);
       }
    }

}
```

For some reason it is not working at the moment of insert and in the select I'm having the next error:
(node:14440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'undefined' in 'where clause'

```
GET /firstlogin?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InJleWVzZUBncnVwb2ludmVyby5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE1OTY3NTE1NDQsImV4cCI6MTU5NjgzNzk0NH0.ZefITNCD7cQ6ZvDMHiTEf4yc9UQI8BKDf9-839agDno 200 12.143 ms - 115
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

I'm not sure why this is happening but all looks fine, ¿do you see something wrong?

Comment: Not sure but I think you should at least use `await` for `pool.query()`

Comment: @Rashomon ok  I change my code, I'm updating in a second, and now I'm getting the next error:
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending two responses to the client (`res.json()`), that its not possible.  Make the first one only be executed when token is invalid:

```js
class FirstloginController {
    async getToken(req, res, next) {
        const { token } = req.params;
        const {access_token} = req.query;
        let decoded
        try {
            decoded = jwt.verify(access_token, process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION)
        } catch (err) {
            res.json({ message: "El acces token es valido", email: decoded})
            return // dont continue the function if token is not valid
        }
        try {
            const email_consulted = res.json({ email: decoded}) // you are returning a success response but you havent finished the process yet. Usually the success is sent on the end of the process
            let select = await pool.query(`SELECT User_email FROM user WHERE User_email=${email_consulted}`)
            if (select != "") {
                const result = await pool.query(`INSERT INTO user (User_email) VALUES (${email_consulted})`);
            }
       } catch (err) {
           next(err);
       }
    }
}
```